# Cannot send ETH to crowdsale contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, crowdsale

my problem is that I cannot send ETH in Rinkeby testnet or truffle to this crowdsale smart contract. I have shared token and crowdsale contract. They compile both in Remix and Mist wallet.
What could be wrong with it?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

//// token contract //////

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract TokenHappyBirthday
 /*ERC20 {

    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint totalSupply);

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance);

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success);

    (o)function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success);

    (o)function approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool success);

    (o)function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint remaining);

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);

    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value);*/

{
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name = "HappyBirthdayToken";
    string public symbol = "HBT";
    uint8 public decimals = 4;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    // total supply beinhaltet amount + decimals 
    uint256 public totalSupply = 10**8;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constructor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    function TokenHappyBirthday(
        /*  uint256 supply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol */
    ) public {
        // totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        // totalSupply = 10**8; // supply;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        // name = "HappyBirthdayToken"; // tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        // symbol = "HBT"; // tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other ccount
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}

//// Crowdsale //////
/*
contract Token { 
    function issue(address _recipient, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {} 
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply) {}
    function unlock() returns (bool success) {}
}
*/
contract HBTCrowdsale {

        // Crowdsale details
    address public beneficiary; // 
    uint256 public minAmount = 1 ether; // ≈ 100 HBT (for test purposes)
    uint256 public maxAmount = 500000 ether; // ≈ 50 mln HBT
    uint256 public maxSupply = 10**8; // 100 mln HBT
    uint256 public minAcceptedAmount = 10**15 wei; // 1/100 ether

    // Eth to HBT rate
    uint256 public rateFirstWeek = 125;
    uint256 public rateSecondWeek = 115;
    uint256 public rateThirdWeek = 105;
    uint256 public rateLastWeek = 100;

    uint256 public rateFirstWeekEnd = 5 minutes; //timeset for testing
    uint256 public rateSecondWeekEnd = 10 minutes;
    uint256 public rateThirdWeekEnd = 15 minutes;
    uint256 public rateLastWeekEnd = 20 minutes;

    enum Stages {
        InProgress,
        Ended,
        Withdrawn
    }

    Stages public stage = Stages.InProgress;

    // Crowdsale state
    uint256 public start;
    uint256 public end;
    uint256 public raised;

    // TokenHappyBirthday
    TokenHappyBirthday public hbtToken;

    // Invested balances
    mapping (address => uint256) balances;


    /**
     * Throw if at stage other than current stage
     * 
     * @param _stage expected stage to test for
     */
    modifier atStage(Stages _stage) {
        if (stage != _stage) {
            revert();
        }
        _;
    }


    /**
     * Throw if sender is not beneficiary
     */
    modifier onlyBeneficiary() {
        if (beneficiary != msg.sender) {
            revert();
        }
        _;
    }


    /** 
     * Get balance of `_investor` 
     * 
     * @param _investor The address from which the balance will be retrieved
     * @return The balance
     */
    function balanceOf(address _investor) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_investor];
    }


    /**
     * Construct
     *
     */
    function HBTCrowdsale(/* */ address _tokenAddress, address _beneficiary , uint256 _start ) {

        //hbtToken = TokenHappyBirthday();
        hbtToken = TokenHappyBirthday(0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c);
        beneficiary =  _beneficiary; 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c; 
        start = 0; 
        end = start + rateLastWeekEnd;
    }

    /**
     * Convert `_wei` to an amount in hbt using 
     * the current rate
     *
     * @param _wei amount of wei to convert
     * @return The amount in hbt
     */
    function toHBT(uint256 _wei) returns (uint256 amount) {
        uint256 rate = 0;
        if (stage != Stages.Ended && now >= start && now <= end) {


            // Check first week
            if (now <= start + rateFirstWeekEnd) {
                rate = rateFirstWeek;
            }

            // Check second week
            else if (now <= start + rateSecondWeekEnd) {
                rate = rateSecondWeek;
            }

            // Check third week
            else if (now <= start + rateThirdWeekEnd) {
                rate = rateThirdWeek;
            }

            // Check last week
            else if (now <= start + rateLastWeekEnd) {
                rate = rateLastWeek;
            }
        }

        return _wei * rate * 10**4 / 1 ether; // 10**4 for 4 decimals
    }


    /**
     * Function to end the crowdsale by setting 
     * the stage to Ended
     */
    function endCrowdsale() atStage(Stages.InProgress) {

        // Crowdsale not ended yet
        if (now < end) {
            revert();
        }

        stage = Stages.Ended;
    }


    /**
     * Transfer raised amount 
     * to the company address
     */
    function withdraw() onlyBeneficiary atStage(Stages.Ended) {

        // Confirm that minAmount is raised
        if (raised < minAmount) {
            revert();
        }
/*
     if (!hbtToken.unlock()) {
            revert();
        }*/

        // 100% eth
        uint256 ethBalance = this.balance;
        if (!beneficiary.send(ethBalance)) {
            revert();
        }

        stage = Stages.Withdrawn;
    }


    /**
     * Refund in the case of an unsuccessful crowdsale. The 
     * crowdsale is considered unsuccessful if minAmount was 
     * not raised before end
     */
    function refund() atStage(Stages.Ended) {

        // Only allow refunds if minAmount is not raised
        if (raised >= minAmount) {
            revert();
        }

        uint256 receivedAmount = balances[msg.sender];
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;

        if (receivedAmount > 0 && !msg.sender.send(receivedAmount)) {
            balances[msg.sender] = receivedAmount;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Receives Eth and issue HBT tokens to the sender
     */
    function () payable atStage(Stages.InProgress) {

        // Crowdsale not started yet
        if (now < start) {
            revert();
        }

        // Crowdsale expired
        if (now > end) {
            revert();
        }

        // Enforce min amount
        if (msg.value < minAcceptedAmount) {
            revert();
        }

        uint256 received = msg.value;
        uint256 valueInHBT = toHBT(msg.value);

/*
        if (!hbtToken.issue(msg.sender, valueInHBT)) {
            revert();
        }
        */

        //transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success)
        hbtToken.transfer(msg.sender, valueInHBT);

        if (now <= start + rateFirstWeek) {

        } else {

            // During the ICO
        balances[msg.sender] += received; // 100% refundable
        }

        raised += received;

        // Check maxAmount raised
        if (raised >= maxAmount || hbtToken.totalSupply() >= maxSupply) {
            stage = Stages.Ended;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you sending the ethers?

Comment: With Mist wallet in Rinkeby testnet to the contract address. At least this is how should it work.